# error adding java package in toaster

Tags: yocto, build-system

I am using yocto krogoth, I have added meta-java in using toaster then its giving below error.

```
ParseError at /home/siva/yocto/toaster/poky/_toaster_clones/_git___git.yoctoproject.org_meta-java_krogoth/recipes-core/jikes/jikes_1.22.bb:12: Could not inherit file classes/relative_symlinks.bbclass
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Down load the file from the link [relative_synlinks.bbclass](https://github.com/openembedded/openembedded-core/blob/master/meta/classes/relative_symlinks.bbclass) and copy in your meta-java/classes dir

Comment: this is working for me but i think this is work around for me is there any other way.

Comment: try to add depends openembedded-core in layer .conf file present in meta-java/

Answer (score 0):

Your layer branches must match: if you use krogoth-branch from poky, you should use krogoth-branch from meta-java as well. You error implies that your meta-java is actually newer.

Comment: Would this only happen to toaster?  Because I use metadata from other branches and most of the time they work well with each other.

Comment: No, in general you get issues if you're mixing branches, it's not related to toaster.
If you for some reason have to mix branches, all bets are off, and you need to be prepared to deal with issues on your own...